# What are the locations of the files that store the list of available users?

Tags: 20.04, users

I know that list of users is present in the `/etc/passwd` file, but are there any other files that have usernames stored in them?

Anonymization of the file system is the intended purpose.

Comment: did you check in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of services that can supply user credentials is in nsswitch.conf:

```
grep passwd /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

for example

```
passwd:         files systemd sss
```

These services correspond to:

- `files`: /etc/passwd
- `sss`: The sssd daemon which pulls credentials from Active Directory, LDAP, IPA, Kerberos, possibly others
- `systemd`: Database driven credentials in /etc/userdb/ instead of traditional flat files

Other services may be possible.

For anonymization rather than credentials, you need to check the above for credentials, and then check the whole system for files owned by any user with a uid >=1000 (or 500 on older systems or 100 on really older systems).  This should catch most user data directories, but especially check `/home` and things like `/var/mail` and `/var/spool/cron` but really all of `/var/spool/` in general.

Also, you need to  check /var for cached credentials.

You may want to carefully purge log files in /var/log which could contain user activity logs.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `/etc/passwd` and `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/` you and @UnKNOWn already mentioned usernames are stored in the following (but not limited to) files:

```
/etc/shadow
/etc/gshadow
/etc/gshadow-
/etc/group
/etc/group-
/etc/subgid
```

Comment: gshadow- and group- have no effect on the system, they are just backup files.

Comment: @user10489 - you are right. Depending on a goal, this file might be needed or not. If the goal is anonymization of the filesystem before transferring it to third party, then usernames should be wiped out from all files including backups.

Comment: That wasn't in the question.

Comment: If anonymization and removal of usernames is a goal, this list is not even close to complete and the OP should add that to the question.

Comment: @user10489 Thanks for pointing that out!  The OP has now updated the question to confirm that anonymization is the goal.